# having issue with refreshing the vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, home-page-layout

We have a VF page to show the reports and add the VF page in the salesforce home page.

[image]

From the above image I will select the item from the drop down and click on show report. We want the page to redirect to the report page with the result. But we are getting something like this.

[image]

its getting refreshed inside the home page vf page not taking me to the new page of report.

[image]

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="ReportController" >

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Choose Report" id="out">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >


                <apex:actionStatus id="actStatusId">
                    <apex:facet name="start">
                        <img src="/img/loading.gif" />
                    </apex:facet>
                </apex:actionStatus>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Choose Report Names">
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedReport}" multiselect="false" size="1">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!reportsOptions}"/>

                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:commandButton value="Show Reports" action="{!showReports}" rerender="out" status="actStatusId"/> 

            </apex:pageBlockSection>


        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock >

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Please advise how to fix.

Comment: Can you share the vf page?

Comment: @Girbot hi please find the code snippet

Comment: @SamuelRobert Can you also add the apex class code snippet used for redirection?

Comment: Post the logic of redirection.

Comment: You have to redirect to this URL, 

Your domain/REPORTID?pv0=OBJECTNAME